# Grazing area for a goat around a circle.

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I am doing this math question and i am really confused on how to approach it.

This is the question:

A retired mathematics professor has decided to raise a goat. He owns a silo and a barn. The barns front wall is tangent to the silo at the corner. The silo has a circular base with a radius of 10 feet. The professor has decided to tether the goat to a chain that is anchored at the corner of the barn, the point of tangency. He has also cut the chain so that it is long enough to wrap around the silo exactly once- that is, the length of the chain equals the circumference of the silo. The barn length is longer than the chain.

This is an image of the barn (square), the silo (circle) and the goat's grazing area.

[image: The drawing.]

The answer I got is -4762.48876, but area is positive, so i made it 4762.48876.

These are the steps i took to getting the answer I have:
[image: The drawing.]
[image: The drawing.]

$$x(\phi)= -R\sin\phi + \phi R\cos\phi, \qquad y(\phi) = R-R\cos\phi - \phi R\sin\phi$$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: To find the total grazing area the goat has.

Comment: You should put that in your question.  You should also include your own attempt to solve the problem and an explanation of where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I added pictures.

Comment: The pictures are sideways.

Comment: I really appoligize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see from the parametrization you've written, you have axis $x$ directed down, and axis $y$ directed left, is that right? That means you have the axes oriented in a way opposite than it's normaly done ($y$ counterclockwise to $x$). This is the origin of your opposite sign.

I suggest using axis $x$ oriented right and axis $y$ oriented up, as that's how they are usually drawn, so it's harder to make a mistake. The center of the coordinate system will be the center of the base of the silo.

You can paramterize the border of the grazing area by
$$ x(\phi)= -R\sin\phi + \phi R\cos\phi, \qquad y(\phi) = -R\cos\phi - \phi R\sin\phi$$
where $R=10 {\rm m}$ and $\phi$ is the angle showing how much of the chain is unwinded and does not follow the circumference of the silo. We have $\phi\in[0,2\pi]$.

We can note that for $x$ initially decreases from $0$ for $\phi=0$ to some $x_{\rm min}<0$ for some $\phi=\phi_0$ (as it will turn out, the value of $\phi_0$ is not important) before it starts icreasing and reaches $x=2\pi R$ for $\phi=2\pi$. For $x<0$ we have two possible values of $y$ one related to $\phi<\phi_0$ and the other from $\phi>\phi_0$. Let's denote them $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$. For $x>0$ we have only $y_2(x)$, but the lower boundary of this region is the wall for $y=-R$.

The full area surrounded by the chain, including the base of the silo, is given by
\begin{align} S &= \int_{x_{min}}^0 (y_2(x)-y_1(x))dx + \int_0^{2\pi R} (y_2(x)-(-R)) dx =\\
&= - \int_{x_{min}}^0 y_1(x) dx + \int_{x_{min}}^{2\pi R} y_2(x) dx + 2\pi R^2=^\text{changing variables} \\
&= - \int_{\phi_0}^0 y(\phi) \frac{dx}{d\phi}(\phi) d\phi + \int_{\phi_0}^{2\pi} y(\phi) \frac{dx}{d\phi}(\phi) d\phi + 2\pi R^2= \\
&= \int_0^{\phi_0} y(\phi) \frac{dx}{d\phi}(\phi) d\phi + \int_{\phi_0}^{2\pi} y(\phi) \frac{dx}{d\phi}(\phi) d\phi + 2\pi R^2= \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} y(\phi) \frac{dx}{d\phi}(\phi) d\phi + 2\pi R^2 = \\
&= (-\pi + \frac43\pi^3)R^2 + 2\pi R^2 = \\
&= (\pi + \frac43\pi^3)R^2
\end{align}

At the end we need to subtract $\pi R^2$, which is the area of the silo's base to get the answer:
$$ A = \frac43 \pi^3 R^2 \approx 4134 {\rm m}^2$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94567/discussion-on-answer-by-adam-latosinski-grazing-area-for-a-goat-around-a-circle).

Comment: Probably another stupid question, but i managed to get the parametric equations for the involute and with the right orientation. However, this is what i got.

Comment: Probably another stupid question, but i managed to get the parametric equations for the involute and with the right orientation. However, this is what i got. ()=−sin+cos,()=−cos−sin .  However, your Y is ()=−cos−sin. Where did you get the R at the front from?

Comment: @DajKatal It was in my original solution (it's not there anymore) and it was just a shift up so that point $(0,0)$ was the point where the goat is chained to, rather than the center of the silo. Doesn't change the geometry at all.

Comment: Thats what i thought, but when i solve it, i get the right answer when I add R to the front, but when i don't, i get the wrong answer.

Comment: You need to remember that the straight line that is the wall of a silo. If you add $R$, it's given by $y=0$ (which doesn't create problems if you forget it), but if you don't add $R$ to $y$ the wall is given by $y=-R$, and if you don't account for this correctly you'll get a wrong result. This accounting for the position of the wall is the source of the term $2\pi R^2$ that appears in my solution above.

Comment: I don't get why u add 2^2

Comment: Or, if u add R to the front of my y equation, what should my reasoning be?

Comment: I don't add it myself, it appears when i calculate $\int_0^{2\pi}(-R)d\phi$. and this part of the integral exists because $y=-R$ is the lower bound of the area i want to calculate. If you add $R$, the reasoning is the same, but the lower boound will be $y=0$ which doesn't produce the extra term at this point. But you're using a slightly differnt $y$, and the final result should be the same.

Answer (score 3):

I have found another, much simpler derivation of the result. Let us divide the area of grazing into infinitesimaly thin triangles, as below:

[image: ![enter image description here]

They all approximately isoceles. The triangle with the apex at point $(R\sin\phi,R-R\cos\phi)$ has the legs of the length  $L(\phi) = (2\pi-\phi)R$ (the length of unwinded chain). they are supposed to be very thin, with the angle at the apex being $\Delta\phi$. Therefore, the area of each triangle is

$$\Delta S \approx \frac12 L(\phi)^2 \sin( \Delta\phi) \approx \frac12 (2\pi-\phi)^2R^2 \Delta\phi$$

The full area is therefore equal to

$$ S = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac12 (2\pi-\phi)^2 R^2d\phi = -\frac{(2\pi-\phi)^3R^2}{6}\Big|_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} = \frac43\pi^3R^2$$

The previous method I've given is more general: it can be used for any area with a boundery with known parametrization. This answer is specific to this problem.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but how exactly did u get Δ≈12()2sin(Δ)≈12(2−)22Δ

Comment: @DajKatal The formula for the area of a triangle $S = \frac12 a b \sin \gamma$ and the approximation $\sin \phi \approx \phi$ for $\phi \approx 0$.

Comment: But why exactly is it ()^2 and not () and how does it become ^2 when the substitution is (2−). I also don't get how the approximation sin≈ for ≈0.

Comment: @DajKatal We have $a\approx b\approx L(\phi)$, so $ab \approx L(\phi)^2 = \big((2\pi-\phi)R\big)^2$. As for the $\sin\phi\approx\phi$, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation